# Find a closed form to $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n} \frac{H_i}{i+1}$

Tags: summation, closed-form

So I'm trying to do this annoying proof and without going into further details I think after quite a while of thinking I found it. Now I get stuck with an annoying sum (of sums..) where I don't quite know if there exists a closed form and if so how to find it.

So as I already said I try to find a closed form to the following series $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n} \frac{H_i}{i+1}$ where $H_n$ is the harmonic series ($\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}$).

So yeah any hint for a closed form of the above series is more than welcome! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The authors in the following wiki try to give a proof for the closed form of $H_n$ which I would mistrust due to  the slightly dodgy way of representing an integral representation of an alternating sum. Check it out though, may get you somewhere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation

Comment: Yeah well besides the dodgy integral this doesn't really help me in this case.  Since it's not only the harmonic series but there's also a sum and a division.. Thanks though!

Comment: I know, but I thought that with a little algebra you could import the division by $i+1$ and manipulate.

Comment: Well I kind of have a closed form if it weren't for the division .. $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n H_i = (n+1) \cdot (H_{n+1} - 1)$ .. what I want to say is that it doesn't matter if I have the harmonic series still in there as long as I can get the other sum away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A preliminary manipulation:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_i}{i+1}=-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{H_i}{i+1}=-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{H_{i+1}}{i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(i+1)^2}$$
gives:
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_i}{i+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{H_k}{k}-\left(H_{n+1}^{(2)}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{1} $$
and now:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{H_k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1}{j}=\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n+1}\frac{1}{j\cdot k}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i}\right)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{i^2}\right] \tag{2}$$
leads to:
$$ \sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_i}{i+1}=\color{red}{\frac{H_{n+1}^2-H_{n+1}^{(2)}-1}{2}}.\tag{3}$$
<sub>Here $H_m^{(2)}$ stands for $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k^2}$, as usual. We exploited $H_{m}=H_{m+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}$.</sub>

Non-believers may just take $(3)$ as a claim and prove it through induction on $n$.
Anyway, the crucial part $(2)$ is just an instance of the following identity:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k}f(j)\cdot f(k)=\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n}f(j)\cdot f(k) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\right)^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)^2\right].$$

Comment: +1 IIRC, there is also an expression involving Stirling numbers of the second kind. Probably not what is expected here though.

Comment: Stirling numbers of the **first** kind in fact. :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: clearly so, just written in a explicit way, depending on generalized harmonic numbers.

Comment: Well first off thanks a bunch! I agree that Stirling numbers are way beyond what I need thanks for that aswell though!

Comment: Sorry didn't realize 'enter' commits my comment.. just one thing could you elaborate why the first equation holds? I don't really see that..

Comment: slowly I feel stupid.. the second equation where you subtract the new sum that becomes $H_{n+1}^2$

Comment: @Desperate: for first I rearrange the sum in order to include the $i=1$ term, then exploit $H_{i+1}=\frac{1}{i+1}+H_i$.

Comment: For $(2)$ you may apply summation by parts or just notice that the middle term can be written as $$\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n+1}\frac{1}{j\cdot k}$$

Comment: I'm sorry I think I wasn't clear enough what was unclear. Before $(1)$ in the very first line why does $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{H_i}{i+1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{H_{i+1}}{i+1} - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(i+1)^2}$ hold?

Comment: @Desperate: already replied: because $H_i=H_{i+1}-\frac{1}{i+1}$.

Comment: aaaaaah I see!!! sorry for the inconvenience I was thinking it would be way less obvious

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Nice answer! But addressing *non-believers* is somewhat strange. It rather indicates you think your answer is of low quality, so that others can believe it or use induction otherwise! For me it's a nicely written and straight forward presentation. But, maybe one or two clarifying comments could reduce the number of *non-believers* preventing them from using induction. :-)  Best regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: you got me, it was a measure for preventing downvotes, indeed. I actually think the stream of thoughts $(1)\mapsto(2)\mapsto(3)$ is not difficult to follow, but... *better safe than sorry* :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I appreciate your nice reply! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

It can be proven also using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) $$S=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_{i}}{i+1}=\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i+1}\cdot H_{i}=H_{n}\left(H_{n+1}-\frac{3}{2}\right)-\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{\left(H_{i+1}-\frac{3}{2}\right)}{i+1}
 $$ hence $$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_{i}}{i+1}=H_{n}\left(H_{n+1}-\frac{3}{2}\right)-\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{H_{i+1}}{i+1}+\frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i+1}
 $$ $$=H_{n}H_{n+1}-\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_{i}}{i+1}+\frac{H_{n}}{n+1}-\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(i+1\right)^{2}}-\frac{9}{4}
 $$ so $$\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{H_{i}}{i+1}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\left(H_{n}H_{n+1}+\frac{H_{n}}{n+1}-H_{n}^{\left(2\right)}-1\right)}.$$
Note that this is the same result of the other answers, since $$H_{n}=H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: (+1) I was going to add this approach to my previous answer, but there is no need now. Well done, as always.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 2}^{n}{H_{i} \over i + 1} & =
\sum_{i = 2}^{n}\braces{{1 \over 2}\bracks{\pars{H_{i} + {1 \over i + 1}}^{2} -
H_{i}^{2} - \pars{1 \over i + 1}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}H_{i + 1}^{2} - {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}H_{i}^{2} -
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 2}^{n}{1 \over \pars{i + 1}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 3}^{n + 1}H_{i}^{2} -
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,H_{2}^{2} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 3}^{n + 1}H_{i}^{2} -
{1 \over 2}\,H_{n + 1}^{2}} -
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 3}^{n + 1}{1 \over i^{2}}\quad
\pars{~\mbox{note that}\ {1 \over 2}\,H_{2}^{2} = {9 \over 8}~}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,H_{n + 1}^{2} - {9 \over 8} -
\pars{-{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 8} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1}{1 \over i^{2}}} =
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{1 \over 2}\,H_{n + 1}^{2} - {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}\,H_{n + 1}^{\pars{2}}}
\end{align}